# Retrieving operations for a transaction unexpectedly slow?

Tags: stellar-core, java-sdk, operations

I am trying to retrieve the operations for the transactions of a given ledger.

First retrieve the transactions:

> ```
>    List<TransactionResponse> transactionResponses = this.server.horizonServer()
>        .transactions()
>        .forLedger(ledger)
>        .execute()
>        .getRecords();
> ```

Then retrieve the operations for each transactions:

> ```
>  List<OperationResponse> operationResponses = this.server.horizonServer()
>      .operations()
>      .forTransaction(transactionHash)
>      .execute()
>      .getRecords();
> ```

The second call is one order of magnitude slower than the first one, for example:

> [PERFORMANCE] getTransactions (10): 34 ms
>   [PERFORMANCE] getOperations (1): 274 ms
>   [PERFORMANCE] getOperations (1): 353 ms
>   [PERFORMANCE] getOperations (1): 294 ms
>   [PERFORMANCE] getOperations (1): 207 ms
>   [PERFORMANCE] getOperations (1): 307 ms
>   [PERFORMANCE] getOperations (1): 309 ms
>   [PERFORMANCE] getOperations (1): 301 ms
>   [PERFORMANCE] getOperations (1): 304 ms
>   [PERFORMANCE] getOperations (1): 293 ms
>   [PERFORMANCE] getOperations (1): 295 ms

Is there a better way of doings this?  We are running our own Stellar node with the official Stellar docker image, so everything (database, stellar-code and horizon) is running locally.

Comment: Do other horizon instances give similar results? (You can try the public https://horizon.stellar.org/)

Answer (score 2):

My best guess is that your PostgreSQL db works inefficiently with indexes on a large collection. Usually it means that your server has not enough RAM and is unable to keep indexes and cache in memory.

In order to find a bottleneck, you can analyze query performance with built-in PostgreSQL [tools](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/sql-explain.html).

Answer (score 2):

If you need all operations per ledger you can use the [Operations for Ledger](https://www.stellar.org/developers/horizon/reference/endpoints/operations-for-ledger.html) endpoint. It won't necessarily be more performant per request but should reduce the number of requests you make.